# Can I index into an array literal in a SELECT statement?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, select

I am reading from a PostgreSQL database (that I do not control) that includes an integer column that acts like an enum, but the enum values are not in the database.

This is not my actual data, but consider an example `students` table:

```
id | name  | class
==================
1  | Adam  | 1
2  | Bruce | 1
3  | Chris | 3
4  | Dave  | 4
```

When `SELECT`ing from this table, it is very common to convert the `class` column to something more humane:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    CASE class
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Freshman'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Sophomore'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Junior'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Senior'
        ELSE 'Unknown'
    END
FROM students
```

Is there a better way to write this? I tried constructing a literal array and using the column to index into it, but if that is possible, I have not figured out the syntax yet.

These don't work:

```
SELECT {"fr", "so", "ju", "se"}[class] FROM students

SELECT '{"fr", "so", "ju", "se"}'[class] FROM students
```

Comment: `SELECT ('{fr,so,ju,se}'::text[])[class] FROM students` if you want to use string constant instead of array constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [ARRAY keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) to construct the array:

```
SELECT (ARRAY['fr', 'so', 'ju', 'se'])[class] FROM students
```

In PostgreSQL, array subscripts begin with `1`, not `0`, so if the enum-like column uses `0` as one of its values, you may need to shift it to get what you want. For example, if the values for `class` were 0, 1, 2, and 3, you can add 1 to `class`:

```
SELECT (ARRAY['fr', 'so', 'ju', 'se'])[class + 1] FROM students
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it a CTE and do the usual join:

```
with class (class, class_name) as ( values
    (1, 'Freshman'),(2,'Sophomore'),(3,'Junior'),(4,'Senior')
), student (id, name, class) as (values
    (1, 'Adam',1),(2,'Bruce',1),(3,'Chris',3),(4,'Dave',4)
)
select id, name, class_name
from
    student
    inner join
    class using (class)
;
 id | name  | class_name                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
----+-------+------------                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  1 | Adam  | Freshman                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  2 | Bruce | Freshman                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  3 | Chris | Junior                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  4 | Dave  | Senior
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-WITH

> The WITH clause allows you to specify one or more subqueries that can be referenced by name in the primary query. The subqueries effectively act as temporary tables or views for the duration of the primary query.